# Silverlight Application.Current.Install()

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I used the Application.Current.Install method to install my OOB application but it keeps saying that the Applicaiton is already installed. I have checked the Start Menu and Desktop but it is not showing.

I am new to this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this - Needed to ensure my Web project was the startup project then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check the control panel and uninstall it. Then reinstall it selecting the add to desktop + start menu options.

Comment: Put this code in your application and see if it is even installed : <code>if (App.Current.InstallState == InstallState.Installed) {}</code>